# django many-to-many compare

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, compare

Is any way to compare two ManyToMany relationship from a different models?

I have a model Days in common and with this other two models:

- Ticket (The Ticket has a m2m relation with Days)
- Check (The check has a m2m relation with Days)

I can do it with two for what don't look really pretty or readable.

Comment: I get the feeling that you should have another look at your data model. If you need to check equality of Tickets based on other criteria than their id, you might be in trouble.

Answer (score 1):

If i'm reading your question correctly, you can achieve what you are asking for by defining related names in the m2m declarations in the Ticket and Check models and then comparing querysets

example:

```
class Day(models.Model):
    day = models.DateField()

class Ticket(models.Model):
    ticket_name = models.CharField()
    days = models.ManyToMany(Day, related_name="tickets")

class Check(models.Model):
    check_name = models.CharField()
    days = models.ManyToMany(Day, related_name="checks")
```

now to find all the tickets and checks for a specified day to compare them you can do:

```
date = datetime.date(day=1, month=1, year=2000)
day = Day.objects.select_related().get(day=date)

ts = day.tickets
cs = day.checks
```

if you want all the checks on the days that are related to a Ticket with ticket_name = ticket:

```
checks_for_ticket = Check.objects.filter(days__tickets__ticket_name="tickets")
```

if you want all the tickets on the days that are related to a Check with check_name = check:

```
tickets_for_check = Ticket.objects.filter(days__checks__check_name="check")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what you're after. Do you want to fetch all the `Ticket`s with the same `days` as the `Check` `day`s?

```
class Day(models.Model):
    # don't know what fields exist..
    date = models.DateField(...)

check = Check.objects.all()[0]
check_dates = [day.date for day in check.days.all()]
tickets_for_check = Ticket.objects.filter(days__date__in=check_dates)
```

This presumes that a Ticket-Day instance with date 'x', has a different id than Check-Day instance with date 'x'. Basically, the same day is a different instance depending on what model it originates from.

Example output would be nice, and also your model description. This should do the trick though. Oh, comparing on a value in a table rather than the ID will perform terribly. Either re-think your data model as @Thomas suggests, or create an index on the `date` property of your `Day` model.